# Send Whatsapp Template with PHP and Messagebird

Tags: php, whatsapp

in our project we use messagebird as an application to send whatsapp messages as reminders to our clients. We are using an endpoint provided by the messagebird Api and in our local environment works but in production it does not send the messages.

We have this function

```
    public static function SendSignatureReminderWhatsapp(array $info)
    {
        $phone  = PhoneHelper::formatPhoneNumber($info['phone']);

        $ch = curl_init();
    
        $url = env('SEND_WHATSAPP_URL');
        
        $data = array(
            "type" => "hsm",
            "to" => $phone,
            "from" => CHANNEL_ID,
            "content" => array(
                "hsm" => array(
                    "namespace" => "TEMPLATE_ID",
                    "templateName" => "reminder",
                    "language" => array(
                        "policy" => "deterministic",
                        "code" => "es_ES"
                    ),
                    "components" => array(
                        array(
                            "type" => "body",
                            "parameters" => array(
                                array(
                                    "type" => "text",
                                    "text" => $info['name']
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "button",
                            "sub_type" => "url",
                            "parameters" => array(
                                array(
                                    "type" => "text",
                                    "text" => $info['link']
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        
        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: AccessKey ". API_KEY,
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        
        curl_close($ch);
        
        Log::info($response);
        Log::info($httpCode);

        
    }
```

The url we are using to make the request is this one `https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/send`, we have a channel id and a template approved.

In the log of the response we are getting nothing and in the log of the http code we are getting a  0.

According to the documentation, if the message is sent correctly the response should be like this one

```
{
  "id": "500a370c86916fe8aef77e4c24b6a6",
  "status": "accepted",
  "fallback": null
}
```

The function works in our local environment but in production it does not work and the whatsapps are not sent.

Comment: Log what curl_errno and curl_error might have to say as well.